# What do square brackets mean in the documentation?

Tags: bash, syntax

How do I interpret square brackets? For example:

The syntax of the 'case' command is:

```
case WORD in
          [ [(] PATTERN [| PATTERN]...) COMMAND-LIST ;;]...
esac
```

I understand how to do the loop but when asking for help from bash documentation I did not know how to interpret the brackets. I mean what the hell does it mean, `[(]`?

Comment: The bash manual uses that to indicate optional parts. You can write the (useless) command `case $word in esac` with no patterns.

Comment: @glennjackman sorry man but thank you I'm learning english  and  i find it difficult to read the manual

Comment: Duplicate on Unix & Linux: [What do square brackets in bash case statement mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164690/117037)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of bash compound commands is defined using the man page synopsis conventions. These are defined in [man(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html):

```
The following conventions apply to the SYNOPSIS section and can be used 
as a guide in other sections.

       bold text          type exactly as shown.
       italic text        replace with appropriate argument.
       [-abc]             any or all arguments within [ ] are optional.
       -a|-b              options delimited by | cannot be used
                          together.
       argument ...       argument is repeatable.
       [expression] ...   entire expression within [ ] is repeatable.
```